# How to use innerHTML in multiple locations?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am trying to dynamically update text in more than one location. However I know the code below doesn't work because the same ID is used more than once.  Any ideas?

```
<html>

Favorite things to eat<p id="fruit">Text will appear</p>
Things that grow on trees<p id="fruit">Text will appear</p>

Dinner<p id="fish">Text will appear</p>
Creature in the ocean<p id="fish">Text will appear</p>

</html>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("fruit").innerHTML="Oranges";
document.getElementById("fish").innerHTML="Shark";

</script>
```

Comment: ID's are supposed to be 100% unique according to HTML5 standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the id multiple times.

You can however assign a class to the element and use jquery to get every element of that class.

```
<p class="fruit">text will appear</p>
```

The script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".fruit").html("Oranges");

</script>
```

Comment: You should also give the non-jquery way, since that's what the OP is using.

Comment: @RUJordan I wanted to tell him about getElementsByClassName but i'm not sure it's supportted across browsers .. not sure why anyone would  refuse to use a lib that makes you worry less about what browser supports what ..

Comment: I'm not against it, but I know in some cases say a class project or a employer would say JS only, no libs. (Not hatin, not downvotin, just sayin)

Comment: @RUJordan Wasn't implying that you were :) .. I was just justifying why i specified the jquery option .. maybe he'll want to try it and stop pulling out his hair :)

Comment: @scartag I write in [_VanillaJS_](http://vanilla-js.com/) because it makes me feel like I _learn JavaScript_, rather than _just using someone else's API_.

Comment: @PaulS. Yes i do too ... but ONLY when i need to ... i'm not out to prove a point but to solve REAL problems with my code :) trying to work around browser quirks just to show that i can will make me grow older than i already am :)

Comment: @RUJordan scartag Paul S.  What makes javascript, in particulalry jquery, a non-desirable solution? Is it only because it is not consistent across all browsers?

Comment: @JohnMontague Jquery is fine to use, they were just suggesting that maybe you had some constraints preventing you from using it. Jquery is consistent across browsers up till version 2.0 where they dropped support for some versions of IE.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the **native** *JavaScript* [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```html
Favorite things to eat <span class="fruit">Text will appear</span>
Things that grow on trees <span class="fruit">Text will appear</span>

Dinner <span class="fish">Text will appear</span>
Creature in the ocean <span class="fish">Text will appear</span>
```

```js
function replaceTextInClass(className, text) {
    var elms = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className), i;
    for (i = 0; i < elms.length; ++i) {
        elms[i].textContent = text;
    }
}
replaceTextInClass('fruit', 'Oranges');
replaceTextInClass('fish', 'Shark');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2x7R/)

You could similarly use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByClassName), the key thing to remember is you have to iterate over a *NodeList* similar to an *Array*.

Answer (score 1):

The same effect would be achieved if you use class instead of id attribute and then with jquery select the elements with that class and set their text like so:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p class="fish"> some fish </p>
  <p class="fish"> other fish </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and then the javascript would be:

```
<script>
$(".fish").html("some text here");
</script>
```

ofcourse you need to add a link to jquery to the html page like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery ..." />
```

Just find the right url. You can find it on jquery.com

Here's non jQuery way for those who don't like it:

Instead of the script above use:

```
<script>
var i, 
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName('fish');
for ( i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
  elements[i].innerHTML = "some text here";
}
</script>
```

This however might not work in some versions of IE.